# add only newest instance object to a list of tuples

Tags: python

I am attempting to store a new instances of user input objects in a tuple and then store each tuple once in a single list.

```
def main():
    global holiday_data_obj 
    global holiday_datastore
    holiday_data_obj = []
    holiday_datastore = []

    while True:
        if input("Add Holiday Package? (y/n) ") == "n":
            break
        else:

            idnum = int(input('Enter your unique id number: '))
            dcity = str(input('Enter your destination city : '))

            add_packages(idnum, dcity)
            print_packages()


def add_packages(idnum, dcity):
    holiday_data_obj.append( HolidayData(idnum, dcity))
    for package in holiday_data_obj:
        F = tuple(package.__dict__.values())
        holiday_datastore.append(F)

def print_packages():    
            print(holiday_datastore)
```

the output pattern i am getting is:

> [(1, 'first city'), (1, 'first city'), (2, 'second city'), (1, 'first
>   city'), (2, 'second city'), (3, 'third city')]

I am aware that my appending logic is faulty. I am am unable to implement a solution that will add only the append the newest tuple input to the list and preserve the previous tuples in the list.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Did you try to change `holiday_datastore` from list to set ?

Comment: i want to store each user input only once, in a simple linear pattern

Comment: the set worked. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The loop inside `add_packages` adds tuples for the full contents of `holiday_data_obj` to the end of `holiday_datastore` on each call. So the first call adds the first element, then the first two, and so on. If you only want to add one item to it, you shouldn't iterate over `holiday_data_obj`, but instead just add a tuple for `holiday_data_obj[-1]`.

Comment: what do i iterate over as i want the numeric and string  representation of each item?

Comment: You don't have to iterate over anything: when you add the object to `holiday_data_object` you can also add its tuple representation to `holiday_datastore` (either by referencing `holiday_data_obj[-1]` or by creating your `HolidayData` instance outside the `holiday_data_obj.append` call and using it in both `append` calls).